# Adding sub element based on data using D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a following html structure

```
<thead class="table-header">   
  <tr>
    <th><div class="th-inner">a</th>
    <th><div class="th-inner">b</th>
    <th><div class="th-inner">c</th>   
  </tr> 
</thead>
```

And I want to add div with class th-but right next to div th-inner based on simple data array with three elements (mydata=['x', 'y', 'z']).

I tried following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
cells = d3.select('root').select('thead.table-header tr')
   .selectAll('div.th-inner').data(mydata)
   .selectAll('div.th-but').data(function(d,i){return d;});

cells.enter().append('div').classed('th-but', true);
```

Am I missing something? Am I going in right direction with solution?

Comment: What is `root`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `div.th-but` to be a sibling of `div.th-inner`, you need to append it to the their parent element `th`. You can use `insert` for this, or select the parent element directly.

```
var cells = d3.select('.table-header tr')
  .selectAll('th').data(mydata)
  .selectAll('div.th-but').data(function(d) { return d; });

cells.enter()
  .append('div')
  .classed('th-but', true);
```

or

```
var cells = d3.select('.table-header tr')
  .selectAll('div.th-inner').data(mydata)
  .selectAll('div.th-but').data(function(d) { return d; });

cells.enter()
  .insert('div')
  .classed('th-but', true);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hughes/oLjw8k8m/1)

Comment: Got it, my problem is that actually my data is an array of objects. Any idea why it doesn't work for objects? Let's assume I only want to add classed <div> Element without any content